# Why can't I build C++ in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, sublimetext2

I am using Windows 7 x64, and I am trying to build C++ code on Sublime Text 2.

```
//C++ Code Here
#include <iostream> 

void main()
{
    cout << "HelloWorld " << endl;
}
```

Then after building (or running), I get an error like below.

```
[Error 2] 
[cmd:  [u'g++', u'C:\\Users\\Johnny\\AppData\\Roaming\\Sublime Text 2\\Packages\\C++\\C++.sublime-build', u'-o', u'C:\\Users\\Johnny\\AppData\\Roaming\\Sublime Text 2\\Packages\\C++/C++']]
[dir:  C:\Users\Johnny\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\C++]
[path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Wizvera\Delfino;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter\Driver;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\APM_Setup\Server\Apache\bin;C:\APM_Setup\Server\MySQL5\bin;C:\APM_Setup\Server\PHP5;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\ESTsoft\ALSee\x64]
[Finished]
```

I found a Sublime Text 2 C++ build script (C++.sublime-build) which has been considered correct to use by some:

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe"]
        }
    ]
}
```

But I'm still getting the same error. It looks like I cannot find any solution to make it able to run a C++-written code on Sublime Text 2. What's wrong with my C++ build configuration?

Comment: LOL, Oops, I solved this problem myself. That was because I didn't have an actual Compiler system like minGW. I setup minGW and could solve it after restarting Sublime Text 2. Hope to be helping someone.

Comment: Thats cool. Maybe type it up as an answer to your own question. I'm sure someone else will have a similar issue to you at some point.

Comment: ST is an **editor**, a more sophisticated version of your notepad. It has no compiler integrated into it. You need one if you want to compile C++ code.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the actual compiler environment, such as MinGW. Sublime Text is only an editor, not a fully fledged IDE, you'll need additional software, such as MinGW or similar.

---

<sup>Note: This answer is based on [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31065438/solved-sublime-text-2-c-building-error-2#comment50152467_31065438) by the original author.</sup>